# How to convert 32 bit NTDLL structures to 64 bit structures?

Tags: c, windows, 64-bit, 32-bit, ntdll

I have a code where i use `NtQuerySystemInformation`, `NtDuplicateObject` and `NtQueryObject` functions to query for opened handles. I use these structures:

```
typedef NTSTATUS ( NTAPI *_NtQuerySystemInformation )
(
ULONG SystemInformationClass,
PVOID SystemInformation,
ULONG SystemInformationLength,
PULONG ReturnLength
);   

typedef NTSTATUS ( NTAPI *_NtDuplicateObject )
(
HANDLE SourceProcessHandle,
HANDLE SourceHandle,
HANDLE TargetProcessHandle,
PHANDLE TargetHandle,
ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
ULONG Attributes,
ULONG Options
);

typedef NTSTATUS ( NTAPI *_NtQueryObject ) 
(
HANDLE ObjectHandle,
ULONG ObjectInformationClass,
PVOID ObjectInformation,
ULONG ObjectInformationLength,
PULONG ReturnLength
);

typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING
{
USHORT Length;
USHORT MaximumLength;
PWSTR Buffer;
} UNICODE_STRING, *PUNICODE_STRING;

typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE
{
ULONG ProcessId;
BYTE ObjectTypeNumber;
BYTE Flags;
USHORT Handle;
PVOID Object;
ACCESS_MASK GrantedAccess;
} SYSTEM_HANDLE, *PSYSTEM_HANDLE;

typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
{
ULONG HandleCount;
SYSTEM_HANDLE Handles[ 1 ];
} SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, *PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;

typedef enum _POOL_TYPE
{
NonPagedPool,
PagedPool,
NonPagedPoolMustSucceed,
DontUseThisType,
NonPagedPoolCacheAligned,
PagedPoolCacheAligned,
NonPagedPoolCacheAlignedMustS
} POOL_TYPE, *PPOOL_TYPE;

typedef struct _OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION
{
UNICODE_STRING Name;
ULONG TotalNumberOfObjects;
ULONG TotalNumberOfHandles;
ULONG TotalPagedPoolUsage;
ULONG TotalNonPagedPoolUsage;
ULONG TotalNamePoolUsage;
ULONG TotalHandleTableUsage;
ULONG HighWaterNumberOfObjects;
ULONG HighWaterNumberOfHandles;
ULONG HighWaterPagedPoolUsage;
ULONG HighWaterNonPagedPoolUsage;
ULONG HighWaterNamePoolUsage;
ULONG HighWaterHandleTableUsage;
ULONG InvalidAttributes;
GENERIC_MAPPING GenericMapping;
ULONG ValidAccess;
BOOLEAN SecurityRequired;
BOOLEAN MaintainHandleCount;
USHORT MaintainTypeList;
POOL_TYPE PoolType;
ULONG PagedPoolUsage;
ULONG NonPagedPoolUsage;
} OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION, *POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION;
```

My app is running fine under Windows XP, Windows 7 32 bit and Windows 7 64bit, but under Windows XP 64 bit it acts strange. It can't receive the right ProcessID's. I will get random negative numbers. However if i compile my code under 64 bit, it works fine.

Is it possible that the i only have to alter on some of the data types of the structures i use, and so it could work fine? If yes, then could someone help me how to do that? If not, then is my only option to use a 64 bit version of my code?

Thanks!

Comment: You are checking return codes, right?  To see if the API had any complaint about the length parameter you passed.

Comment: What negative number do you get specifically?  If you fill the buffer with a known value ahead of time, is the buffer content preserved, or is the API writing something to it?

Comment: Of course i check it. With the length there is no problem. The functions executes successfully,it just doesn't returns the crrect data :(

Comment: Is `ReturnLength` the same on XP64 and Win7-64?

Comment: @BenVoigt: No the returnlength is not the same. It is alway bigger on XP 64 bit, then on Windows 7 64 bit. And i forgot to tell you, that on XP 64 bit, only the PID of my app will be returned, every other is 0. I don't know how i got those negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The 64-bit version of XP is, erm, special.  Training wheels for Microsoft getting the 64-bit version of Windows right, a very nontrivial job.  They nailed it completely at Vista, the first real Windows version that got *everything* right.  In spite of the hate.

I still have olden MSDN Library documentation for NtQuerySystemInformation() on my machine, dates from 2008 but was probably written well before that.  It exposes a pretty hilarious view of what the programmers thought about the settlement with the DOJ in the USA.  I can't link it anymore so I'll just copy/paste:

> Returns an opaque *something* structure that can be used to generate an unpredictable seed for a random number generator.

Where *something* was cued from most of the SystemInformationClass arguments you passed.  That got toned down quite a bit since then, no more sharky comments in the documentation for the function.  In no small part enabled by the ntddi version stabilizing at Vista, no more need for training wheels.  XP was version 5 of Windows.  Vista was Windows version 6.0, very major kernel revision.  Win7 is 6.1, Win8 is 6.2.  Service packs, really, with enough UI gadgets to get somebody to pay for the update.  Don't bother making it work in XP, nobody actually uses it.

Comment: Thanky for your reply! I know that the 64 bit version of XP special, but unfortunately, i have to make it work, because we have some very special system running on 64 bit XP, and 99% probabely we will have to use it, because those application don't run under Windows 7 64 bit. I don't know if they ever will, but right now, they don't :(

Comment: Contact Microsoft Support to find help.  Not sure if XP is still being supported, you'll find out quickly.